# Minimum date by streaming list with a list java 8

Tags: java, java-stream

I am trying to write streams to iterate through list within a list to find the minimum date. The following is what I have tried.

```
listA.stream().flatMap(t -> t.listB().stream()).map(v ->v.getDate()).min((b1,b2 ) -> b1.compareTo(b2));
```

But the above piece of code is giving Optional but I need Date. Can someone tell where I am doing wrong?

Comment: You should be able to use `Comparator.naturalOrder()` instead of `(b1,b2 ) -> b1.compareTo(b2)`.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

`Optional` allows you to avoid `null` values. It's protecting you, so to speak. You have to get the value from it. See the [Javadocs](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html)

> A container object which may or may not contain a non-null value. If a
>   value is present, isPresent() will return true and get() will return
>   the value.

You may also choose to use [Optional#orElse](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/Optional.html#orElse-T-) to avoid the check and provide a default date automatically when the `Optional` is empty.

In the case of [Stream#min](https://docs.oracle.com/javase/8/docs/api/java/util/stream/Stream.html#min-java.util.Comparator-) an empty `Optional` is returned if the stream is empty or one describing the minimum value. So, it's possible to call `min`, or `max`, on an empty stream.

Comment: Maybe explain how it relates to `Stream.min()`.

Comment: u mean to say its fine use optioanl date instead of date

Comment: @pppavan, if you're confident there's at least one date in the stream, just add `.get()` at the end.

Comment: It's not an optional date. An optional is it's own type that is an alternative to dealing with `null` values when looking for an absent value. It may be empty itself so you can call `isPresent` on the optional and if it's `true` then you'd `get()` it. Or do as shmosel says if you're sure about it.

Answer (score 2):

```
final Optional<Date> min = listA.stream().flatMap(t -> t.listB().stream()).map(v ->v.getDate()).min((b1,b2 ) -> b1.compareTo(b2));

if(min.isPresent()) {
    final Date minDate = min.get();
    // do whatever you want
}
```

Comment: Please add more details about your solution